# I dont understand what is wrong with this code

Tags: discord, discord.js

My code is used so it generates random rarities based on how many you want to generate but I keep getting the syntax error:

> `i` is not defined

With this code:

```js
var rarities = [
    'Common',
    'Uncommon',
    'Rare',
    'Epic',
    'Legendary',
    'Exotic',
    'Mythic'
]

let rarity = rarities[Math.floor(Math.random() * rarities.length)

function generateRarity(length, times){
    let numbers = [];
    for(i=0; i < times; i++){
        let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * length)
        numbers.push(number)
    }
    return numbers;
}

let indexArray = generateRarity(rarities.length, args) 
let generatedRarities = [];
indexArray.forEach(index => generatedRarities.push(rarities[index]))

sentrarities = "#".join(generatedRarities)

await message.reply(sentrarities)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error only because of a typo. When you are declaring `let rarities`, you are missing an `]` at the end of it. JS then tries to include the function in it but then finds out that it can't so the error comes. All you have to do is change your code to:

```js
var rarities = [
  'Common',
  'Uncommon',
  'Rare',
  'Epic',
  'Legendary',
  'Exotic',
  'Mythic'
]
let rarity = rarities[Math.floor(Math.random() * rarities.length)]

function generateRarity(length, times) {
  let numbers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * length)
    numbers.push(number)
  }
  return numbers;
}

let indexArray = generateRarity(rarities.length, args)
let generatedRarities = [];
indexArray.forEach(index => generatedRarities.push(rarities[index]))

sentrarities = "#".join(generatedRarities)

await message.reply(sentrarities)
```

Comment: Edited the question because i need more help.

Comment: You are getting this error because `i` has not been initialised. So all you have to is change the first line of the for loop to: `for(var i=0; i < times; i++)`